# ppa.launchpad.net does not support https

Tags: apt, package-management, security, ppa

I use a number of software packages that I get via ppas. I just spent some time trying to replace the http URLs for them with https, to no avail. Why is there no cert for ppa.launchpad.net? Doesn't that leave everyone subject to Man-In-The-Middle attacks?

I see that this was discussed in this thread here:
[download packages from ppa.launchpad.net via ftp or https](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30728/download-packages-from-ppa-launchpad-net-via-ftp-or-https)

but it is nearly 10 years old, and it doesn't actually explain why there is no https. Doesn't this just require putting in a cert for ppa.launchpad.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the packages you download from launchpad are all cryptographically signed just like with every other debian repository, a man-in-the-middle attack is not really feasible. `apt` checks the signature of the downloaded `.deb` files and any tampering would lead to an invalid signature. Invalid signatures cause an error prior to installation. So I don't see this as a major problem from a security perspective.

One could argue that it is a violation of privacy as anyone listening in on the connection could see which software you are installing. Therefore, an HTTPS connection would indeed be preferable.

As for your last question regarding if they couldn't just add the certificate and be done with it, we both don't know how the infrastructure behind ppa.launchpad.net works. For a single server things are often that simple. But I doubt that we are talking about a single simple server. The infrastructure is probably more complicated than that and therefore the setup may be more complicated. There are also issues regarding server load to consider, as encrypting all outgoing traffic requires a lot more CPU cycles than just delivering it. Depending on the volume of traffic they receive this may cause significant load on the server which they might not want to handle. But please bear in mind that this is just speculation on my part and the reasons might be entirely different.

Comment: Thanks Lienhart Woitok for your reply. It seems to me that many of the ppas don't actually sign their deb files. For example when I installed the git ppa (https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) I didn't add any keys in order to download. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Some keys are added automatically using Ubuntu keyring, apt outputs this as msg when adding ppa. I was actually going through same thought process this morning 

Comment: @MitchGolden, I keep the software mkusb up to date and distribute it via PPA, and I can verify that there are cryptographic signatures. If this does not work correctly, for example because of a bad internet connection, there is an error output from the installing or update/upgrade process. When things work correctly, you will not notice that the download was checked. - But there is another problem. You have to rely on the developer/maintainer of the program package, and I know several people who avoid using software via PPA because lack of trust.

Comment: @LuxZg - I started thinking about this because I was triaging tickets for Kubuntu Muon, which is a package manager.  One of the bugs mentioned a MITM attack and https. I tried to change all my deb lines to https, but wasn't able to to it for the ppas.

Comment: @LuxZg How do I see the keys being added? I seem to be able to make ppas work by simply adding the appropriate file in sources.list.d. I don't need to do anything at the command line.

Comment: I was installing certbot today, and added repo like this `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot` and I got msg like `requesting key 75BCA694 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com` (msg copied from web, I'm not at PC now). Unsure if any msg is shown if you just added directly to sources list. But hopefully the msg above helps you in your search. It makes sense it's logged somewhere.

Comment: @LuxZg Ok, interesting.

Comment: @sudodus Are you actually required to encrypt with the keys to put it in the ppa? It's not optional in any way?

Comment: @sudodus It is of course true that I have to trust the application I am downloading. I sort of think that a ppa is likely to be below the radar for most bad guys. But, for example, Audacity is released by ppa, and I wonder if the fact that it's a larger group actually makes it more rather than less likely to be a Trojan for something. (Not that I really believe audacity is a trojan!)

Comment: @MitchGolden, 1. Yes, I am actually required to put a signature (not encrypt) with the key (for mkusb) to put it in the ppa; 2. You can get `audacity` from Ubuntu's `universe` repository which is more official (and reliable?) compared to a PPA. The version in the PPA is often newer, but not tested by Ubuntu; the version in `universe` can do what I need (but I don't know, maybe you need the newest version).

Comment: @sudodus I believe that the ppa is actually maintained by the audacity developers. I haven't run into any issues with it.

Comment: @MitchGolden, I think you know enough about the `audacity` PPA in order to use it :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Launchpad now supports HTTPS (2022)

Launchpad has finally launched support for serving PPAs over HTTPS!

So you can now do a find and replace of any apt sources.list files that refer to the old domain:

- http://ppa.launchpad.net/ → https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/
- https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/ → https://private-ppa.launchpadcontent.net/

This is a big improvement for privacy, since eavesdroppers can no longer see what PPAs you visit or what packages / OS versions you download.

Using HTTPS to provide transport layer security also adds defense in depth, in case a vulnerability is discovered in GnuPG or in the apt package signing mechanisms. This has happened several times in years past, so this is a big improvement.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1473091

There's another ticket (still open as of 2022-02-07) to change `add-apt-repository` to prefer HTTPS by default.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1959015

Comment: This is great. Now all of my ppas are https. Thanks for doing this.

Comment: Actually, Launchpad DOWNGRADES https to http currently:  `curl -D- https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu` gives `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
date: Wed, 07 Feb 2024 02:05:17 GMT
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
location: http://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/`  This made `apt-cacher-ng` fail on my side ..  (And yes, it worked with the workaround `http://HTTPS///ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/` before)

Comment: @Tino you're supposed to have a trailing slash `/` on those apt repo URLs. Evidently the no-slash --> slash redirect doesn't use https, which isn't good, but that shouldn't matter if you use the correct URL to start with.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there no cert for ppa.launchpad.net?

See Launchpad [bug 1473091](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1473091): default PPAs to HTTPS

William Grant (wgrant) replied on 2015-07-10:

> This is non-trivial due to the arbitrary content served on the domain. We would do better to move it away from ppa.launchpad.net entirely.

Colin Watson (cjwatson) replied on 2017-03-27:

> It would require deciding on and acquiring a suitable domain for this that isn't under launchpad.net (compare e.g. launchpadlibrarian.net, which exists for the same reason), since otherwise an XSS attack by user-supplied content on ppa.launchpad.net would be able to steal cookies from its launchpad.net superdomain. We're currently saved by the Secure attribute, but that would become ineffective if ppa.launchpad.net were served over HTTPS. It would of course then require reconfiguring various things to point to that, and I would expect quite a bit of miscellaneous fallout; it's the sort of task that requires budgeting a lot of time for debugging.

Colin Watson (cjwatson) elaborated on 2020-02-03:

> Launchpad needs to set the domain of its session cookies to ".launchpad.net" so that they're visible by its other virtual hosts (code.launchpad.net, bugs.launchpad.net, etc.), but this also causes them to be visible to all other subdomains of launchpad.net. We also set the "secure" flag on those cookies, which mitigates this by ensuring that browsers at least only send them over HTTPS. However, if ppa.launchpad.net were accessible over HTTPS, then any page there would be able to exfiltrate your session cookie. While I don't currently know of a way to get ppa.launchpad.net to serve arbitrary content with Content-Type: text/html, it's a service that hosts a great deal of user-generated files, and it wouldn't take that much to construct abuses of it that would confuse browsers. We need to move it before using HTTPS is safe.

Colin Watson (cjwatson) began actions to resolve the bug on 2021-09-28:

> I've filed https://portal.admin.canonical.com/C133313 (internal link only) asking our sysadmins to register another domain so that we can start making progress on this.

On 2021-09-30:

> The alternate domain in question has been registered, and I've filed https://portal.admin.canonical.com/C133345 (again, internal link only) to get it configured on the relevant host.

Comment: @Community Everything is cited from bug 1473091 that is linked at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Community is a robot, there's no need to reply to it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here and looking for a quick fix based on the solutions above:

- PPA sources now support HTTPS! But you must change the hostname as well
- Edit the PPA sources listed in the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
- Change the base URL from http://ppa.launchpad.net/
  to https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/
- run `apt update`