# Update ppa.launchpad.net from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Hey so I was looking into securing my PPA's from HTTP to HTTPS and I found this article:

[ppa.launchpad.net does not support https](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293702/ppa-launchpad-net-does-not-support-https)

Since Launchpad does support https, i have tried updating my source list:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

from http to https:

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 21.10 _Impish Indri_ - Release amd64 (20211012)]/ impish main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 22.04 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main multiverse restricted universe
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy universe
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy multiverse
deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


deb https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.




deb https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/ jammy-backports universe restricted main multiverse
```

I get error messages:

```
Err:1 https://ubuntu.securedservers.com jammy InRelease
  Could not connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:443 (108.170.47.58). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 https://ubuntu.securedservers.com jammy-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:https:
Err:3 https://ubuntu.securedservers.com jammy-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:https:
Err:8 https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.36). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:443 (108.170.47.58). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:https:
W: Failed to fetch https://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.36). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (185.125.190.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.39). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:443 (91.189.91.38). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch https://ubuntu.securedservers.com/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ubuntu.securedservers.com:https:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

Lauchpad might but you use `ubuntu.securedservers.com` and they do not.

Have a look and see what happens when you open

https://ubuntu.securedservers.com

and when you open

http://ubuntu.securedservers.com

And no it is NOT a good idea to switch to `ubuntu.securedservers.com` That domain is NOT owned by Canonical so whatever happens on that server is untrusted.

Comment: if I want update ppa from http to https, where do i update from? Is it located in Software Sources?

Comment: I don't see anything related to PPA in your question. Do you know what a PPA is?

Comment: @krillavilla 1st you need to add a ppa from launchpad. You have none. ubuntu.securedservers.com is not launchpad.